# Why every time I deploy the index.html file is added to production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I already deleted the index.html in my development machine. I checked in the change in github. Then I deploy, and it adds index.html to my public directory. Why?!

Comment: are you sure the file was removed from your rep? what command do you use for commit?

Comment: git add . | 
git commit -m 'some message' | 
git push

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so:

```
git commit -m "comment"
```

doesn't delete files from your git repo.

Do:

```
git commit -a -m "comment"
```

You can also do:

```
git rm path/to/file
git commit -m "comment"
```

[See doc here](http://gitref.org/basic/#commit) and [here](http://gitref.org/basic/#rm-mv).

Answer (score 0):

or you could do `git add -u .` to queue up deleted files and then commit